# Java StringTokenizer assistance

Tags: java, eclipse, file, bufferedreader, stringtokenizer

So, I have a separate program that requires a string of numbers in the format: final static private String INITIAL = "281043765"; (no spaces) This program works perfectly so far with the hard coded assignment of the numbers. I need to, instead of typing the numbers in the code, have the program read a txt file, and assign the numbers in the file to the INITIAL variable

To do this, I'm attempting to use StringTokenizer. My implementation outputs [7, 2, 4, 5, 0, 6, 8, 1, 3]. I need it to output the numbers without the "[]" or the "," or any spaces between each number. Making it look exactly like INITIAL. I'm aware I probably need to put the [] and , as delimiters but the original txt file is purely numbers and I don't believe that will help. Here is my code. (ignore all the comments please)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class test {
//public static String num;
static ArrayList<String> num;
//public static TextFileInput myFile;
public static StringTokenizer myTokens;
//public static String name;
//public static String[] names;
public static String line;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try {
        File file = new File("test3_14.txt");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        num = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {       


            myTokens = new StringTokenizer(line, " ,");
            //num = new String[myTokens.countTokens()];

               while (myTokens.hasMoreTokens()){
                   num.add(myTokens.nextToken());

            }        
         }    
            System.out.println(num);   

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You are currently printing the default `.toString()` implementation of ArrayList.  Try this instead:

```
for (String nbr : num) {
   System.out.print(nbr)
}
```

Comment: Hey, i tried your suggestion and the output does look exactly how I want. But I believe your implementation prints out one digit every iteration. How would I assign all the numbers to a variable if only one is retrieved each time?

Comment: instead of `System.out.print(nbr)` append to a StringBuffer in the loop `strBuff.append(nbr)` and then `String final = strBuff.toString()` after the loop.

Comment: After doing what you suggested my code looks like                                             'for (String nbr : num) {
       StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
       sBuffer.append(nbr);
      
      }
      String plz = sBuffer.toString();'  I can't access the sBuffer.toString after the loop because its outside of the loop and gives me an error? i think

Comment: move `StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer()`  line before the loop so it's still in scope after the loop.

Comment: Hey man, I've been tinkering with your suggestions and actually completely solved the problem i had. Thank you for taking your time and helping this struggling college student.. lol..   PS. (this is a slightly different question that i came across when trying to integrate this code snippet to my actual program.)  When trying to assign this finished  String variable to another String variable  I get the error message "PLL cannot be resolved to a variable". Is there a simple solution to this?

Comment: @SirBrill - You should introduce yourself to a debugger, the sooner the better.  Are you using Eclipse or some other Java IDE?  Are you trying to assign the finished value like `PLL = plz`?  If so, make sure you've declared `String PLL` before you try to assign to it. `String PLL = plz;`

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of the brackets, you have to actually call each item in the ArrayList.  Try this just below your System.out.println

```
for(String number : num)
    System.out.print(number);
System.out.println("");
```

Can you also provide sample input data?

Comment: Hey thanks, your suggestion worked too for just getting it to output in the right format. But how would i then assign those numbers to a variable if only one digit is printed each iteration?  and by sample data do you mean the txt file? it is this  7 2 4
                      5 0 6
                      8 1 3

Comment: Yes, I was referring to the data in the txt file.  Each number is also separated by spaces?  Are you wanting to assign each number to it's own variable?  I'm not quite sure I understand what your end goal is.

Answer (score 0):

Try Replacing `space` and `,` with `empty` string

```
line = StringUtils.replaceAll(line, “,” , “”);
line = StringUtils.replaceAll(line, “ “, “”);
System.out.println(line);
```